# Swift Sprite-kit move object

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am using coreMotion to move my main character right now but i am running into device orientation problems after while with this code.

```
    manager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
    let data = manager.accelerometerData
    manager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.0001
    manager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){
        (data, error) in
        self.plane.physicsBody!.applyForce(CGVectorMake(120.0 * CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)!), 0))
    }
```

So My New question is, How can I move my object with a touch on left side of screen or touch on right side of screen, so that the character moves smoothly across and can back and fourth on the x-axis with no problems?

Comment: that is a lot of force you are applying,  why are you updating at 0.001, 1/60th of a second is .016666666667,  you are putting too much work on the acceleroometer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every SKScene has 4 touches methods (began, ended, moved, cancelled) which you can use.

For example

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
     for touch in touches {
         let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

         if location.x < frame.midX { // left side
              plane.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVectorMake(-120.0, 0)) // move left
         } else {
              plane.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVectorMake(120.0, 0)) // move right
         }
     }
}
```

Adjust the 120 to a value you like, also depends how big your sprite is.

Hope this helps

Comment: that makes sense But it gives an error saying cant convert type of CGPoint to expected argument type of CGFloat? @crashoverride777

Comment: Yeah sorry just updated my answer. You need to say if location.x < ..... I forgot the .x